# RelativeLayout MarginLayoutParams resize ImageView make it very small

Tags: android, imageview, android-relativelayout

I have a ImageView and its src is a animation-list when I try to to set it margins programmatically it also resize the imageview very very small.

```
        ImageView hand = (ImageView)rlRoot.findViewById(R.id.ivHandAnimation);

        MarginLayoutParams marginsParams = new MarginLayoutParams(hand.getLayoutParams());
        marginsParams.setMargins(this.getLeft(), rlRoot.getMeasuredHeight() - 20, 0, 0);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(marginsParams);
        //lp.height = rlRoot.findViewById(R.id.btnHole_14).getMeasuredHeight();
        hand.setLayoutParams(lp);

        if (hand != null) {

            hand.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)hand.getDrawable();
            frameAnimation.setCallback(hand);
            frameAnimation.setVisible(true, true);
        }
```

I have tried to set lp.height but it is not working. And I also create LayoutParams with following code.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to answer this question. In my case when ImageView resized it keeps its first width and height when I set the margins  `hand.setLayoutParams(lp);` using `android:adjustViewBounds` property fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in `rlRoot.getMeasuredHeight() - 20`. `rlRoot.getMeasuredHeight()` inside onCreate method returns you 0. so rlRoot.getMeasuredHeight() -20 means you are reducing height by 20 pixel.

Comment: no it not inside onCreate method it is in a Button click event and the getMeasuredHeight code returns a value I checked it.

even if it is true it should not change the width and height I set it as margin top value of the imageview.